# Indian Railway Train Search API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, screen-scraping

Is there any API provided by Indian Railways to search its train network, time-tables etc. There are many sites out there which show time-table etc. I searched Google but couldn't find any info on Web services or APIs provided by Railways. Is data scraping the only way?

Comment: View the source code of their web page ... developers are used to put in there names for every change they make there !!.. call them and ask :)

Answer (score 17):

You need to be a big shot to use their api  ( i can't understand why you need to show a turnover of Rs 5 crores to use their API )

Indian Railways opened up it’s ticket booking APIs a few weeks back and here are some fine prints that you need to understand:

```
* Must have minimum annual turnover (i.e. Gross transaction value) of Rs.5 crore in last financial year from Travel business.
* The OTA will be required to submit a one time non refundable deposit of Rs. 20 lakh once the proposal is approved by IRCTC.
```

Here is their address:
The Group General Manager/ITS
Indian Railway Catering & Tourism Corporation Ltd.,
Ist Floor, Internet Ticketing center,
IRCA Building
State Entry Road
New Delhi-110055.
Ph-011 23741113 / 23345804,05 Ext- 614,621,620,619
e-mail id – eoi@irctc.co.in

Comment: simply ridiculous. Any change till this day?

Comment: one can check the terms & conditions `http://api.erail.in/terms`

Answer (score 0):

Now railway API is available. Please visit http://www.railwayapi.com/

Comment: but they are not responding to my mail about a quotation