# Extracting mysql data from other server

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen a few websites which are allowing live status of indianrail.gov. Status such as real-time availability is visible in their websites. My question is how do they do this?
As we are not knowing the mysql user name, database name and password of other servers then how we can extract data in real-time. Here is one example: this website clearly states in the top that we are not affilated to indian railway then also they are able to show data, any light will be appreciated

```
       http://indiarailinfo.com/     the website which is showing other data
```

Comment: Indian Railway might have given them an API for that. Or they might be Scraping the website content to generate status messages on their own site

Comment: take a look into this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466045/indian-railway-train-search-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are asking How site `A` can display information from site `B`? Usually, this is all done in site `B` - this site has a web service that site `A` calls to get the data. All site `A` needs is the url to the service. In order for the service to work with site `A`, it should have its set of requirements and format, and site `B`'s service should conform to that format.

Comment: where i can get that url

Comment: for indian railway - look at their site - they might provide an API - a service that you call